# How to change the scope of an thread in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, pthreads

i am trying to create an program which sets the scope of an POSIX thread in linux .. I am using pthread_attr_setscope() for setting the scope of the thread to process context but it is set to default as system. Is there any way to change the thread scope in linux ? I am using Ubuntu with a 3.8.2 kernel

Answer (score 1):

This is not implemented in the Linux kernel.

glibc's `pthread_attr_setscope` stores the setting in the `pthread_attr` structure so that it can be retrieved later with `pthread_attr_getscope`, but that's all it does.